# How to delete data from html form php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm new to php and I learned some stuffs like adding data but I got stuck in deleting data from html form.
Here's my code.

database name: mydb

tablename : registered

HTML

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<form method="post" action="dataout.php">
ID:<input type="Text" id="idelete" name="idelete"><br>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="delete">
</form>
</HTML>
```

dataout.php

```
<HTML>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","");
mysqli_select_db($db,"mydb");
$id=$_POST['idelete'];
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM registered WHERE id=$id",$db);
echo "Information Deleted";
?>
</body>
</HTML>
```

When I click the button nothing appears, no errors and nothing;
please help me.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: When you are submitting the form, does the `idelete` field have the right ID to delete? Are the values (host, username, password and database name) inside your connection correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM registered WHERE id=$id",$db);
```

the connection comes first in `mysqli_` and not last.

```
mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM registered WHERE id=$id");
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

> mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

You could also do it all in one go, without using `mysqli_select_db`

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
```

You should also use conditional statements along with `isset()` and `empty()`.

Also make sure the id being passed through is an `int`. Otherwise, you will need to quote it.

I.e.:

```
mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM registered WHERE id='$id'");
```

---

Sidenote: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Make use of error reporting/checking for both PHP and MySQL.

Consult:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

**Edit:**

Do the following:

```
mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM registered WHERE id='$id'")
  or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

to see if errors come of it from your query.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

---

**Edit #2:**

Replace:

```
$id=$_POST['idelete'];
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM registered WHERE id=$id",$db);
```

with:

```
if(!empty($_POST['idelete'])){
$id=$_POST['idelete'];
}
$query = "DELETE FROM registered WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if ( !$result ) {
    trigger_error('query failed', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

and see if any errors come of it.

- If you see "query failed...", then your query failed.
- You will need to find out why.

Comment: @Emmanuel it doesn't work doesn't help me. Plus, I hope you'll be marking it as an edit under your original post.

Comment: im still new here im confused sorry im trying

Comment: @Emmanuel if you're using your HTML form and PHP/MySQL inside the same file, you need to use a conditional statemen around the executable code. Also, do you have a webserver setup? Is the file `.php` extension? Too many things can be an issue here.

Comment: @Emmanuel what you did, isn't how things are done on Stack. You updated your question and overwrote everything with my code in there without marking it as an edit. I stand at getting downvoted for it, once people see the correct method and tell themselves: *"the db parameter is ok, so why the answer?"*. I have performed a rollback to the original question and you can add on to it after.

Comment: im sorry im really confused here

Comment: @Emmanuel Reload my answer and look near the bottom under **Edit:**. there are a few ways to check for errors. Plus, since I noticed you are running under Wamp, make sure your server's properly setup and that the file is `.php` extension for the PHP/MySQL. If you made changes to your server, make sure you restarted all services and that all services are all indeed running.

Comment: @Emmanuel The "id" column needs to be of `int` type and not `varchar` if that is what you're using. Also, you need to make sure that whatever you enter in that input, must exist in your database. what value are you passing in that?

Comment: yes the id is using INT and the database is good, the wamp is also running fine

Comment: @Emmanuel as I said, check for errors as outlined in my answer and make sure the `id` number you're passing in the input exists in your table and that there are no spaces anywhere, including during your input. That is about as far as I can help with this, since I can't see anything else causing problems. I too run Wamp.

Comment: @Emmanuel Reload my answer again, and look near the bottom again, under **Edit #2:**. If that fails, you'll need to find out why. I have to go to bed now, so I hope this gets resolved. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're misplacing db connection parameter

```
mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM registered WHERE id=$id");
```

Comment: *"You're missing db connection parameter"* - it's not missing, it's misplaced

Comment: Correct. My answerer looks absolute wrt yours . and can't delete from phone

Comment: i have updated my code but still it doesnt work. im using WAMP server and it worked before when im adding data but im having problem in deleting i just want a simple code to delete data for a beginner i would like to explore the injection thingy later

Comment: Your files are in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

wel come to PHP

here is simple & understandable sample code

html

```
<form method="post" action="dataout.php">
ID:<input type="Text" id="idelete" name="idelete"><br>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="delete">
```

dataout.php file

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");  //my sql connection create
mysql_select_db("mydb")or die("Connection Failed"); // data base connection
$id = $_POST['idelete']; delete feiled id
$query = "delete from registered  where id = '".$id."'";  //query 
if(mysql_query($query)){ //check is true or false 
 echo "deleted id ".$id." ";//out put if ture
 }
 else{ 
 echo "Delete fail";//out put if false
} 
?>
```

i hope this will be help to improve your php 
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm